Integer Linear Programming - Dividing n people into m groups
I have modeled the problem of dividing n people into m groups using a binary $nxn$ matrix that we will call X.
If $x_{ij} = 1$ it means that person i is with person j in the solution's groups. If $x_{ij} = 0$ then person i is not with person j in the solution's groups.
I have arbitrarily chosen $x_{ii} = 1$.
One of the several constraints I have modeled is the minimum ($min$) and maximum ($max$) people allowed in each group. These constraints are simply enforced by summing the elements of each row of the X matrix and having the result be greater than or equal to $min$ and less than or equal to $max$.
However, these constraints are not enough to enforce the division of the n people into exactly m groups. For example, if n = 10 and m = 4, I can set $min$ to 2 and $max$ to 3 in order to divide the 10 people into 4 groups: 2 groups of 2 people and 2 groups of 3 people. But the solver I am using would not be to blame if it divides the 10 people into 5 groups of 2 people each because it is respecting the $min$ and $max$ constraints perfectly fine.
This is why I am asking this question. How can I enforce the solver to divide the people into exactly m groups? In other words, I need a mathematical restriction that tells the solver that the solution matrix X can only have m groups of identical rows/columns.
Thank you in advance!

You don't have an index for a group. If you introduce such an index it is straightforward to formulate constraints which garantees a range of number of groups.

@callculus42 What do you mean by having an index for a group?

$x_{ij}=1$: Person $i$ is in group is in group $j$.

But that means remodeling the whole problem in a different way, right? I considered that model before implementing the one I described in the question but I have an objective function that I have to maximize and if I went for your approach, then that function would be non linear and much more complicated.

Your model is already non-linear, from what I've understood from your post. Assignment problems are usually non-linear.

All my restrictions are linear and so is the objective functions. The objective function is simply the sum of all the elements of the X matrix where each elemet is multiplied by binary coefficients that are given to the problem as an input. Isn't it there a way to solving the problem I explained in the question without changing the meaning of what a variable (xij) means?

I agree with @callculus42 about the choice of variables, but sticking with your definition of $x_{ij}$ you can implement the constraint you want by adding binary variables $y_{ig}$ ($i$ indexing the person, $g$ indexing the group). $y_{ig}=1$ will indicate that person $i$ is the "anchor" for group $g.$ The added constraints will be:

Every group has exactly one anchor: $$\sum_i y_{ig} = 1 \quad \forall g.$$
Nobody can anchor more than one group: $$\sum_g y_{ig} \le 1 \quad \forall i.$$
Two people in the same group cannot both be anchors: $$\sum_g y_{ig} + \sum_g y_{jg} \le 2 - x_{ij} \quad \forall j\neq i.$$

EDIT: There was an omission in the above solution: nothing prevents the formation of a cluster of individuals that belongs to no indexed group. Under the assumptions that $x_{ij} = x_{ji}$ for all $i \neq j$ and $x_{ii}=1$ for all $i,$ we deal with this by introducing new binary variables $z_{ijg},$ where $z_{ijg}=1$ if and only if individuals $i$ and $j$ are in the same group and individual $j$ anchors group $g.$ Additional constraints are as follows.

Defining $z$: $z_{ijg}=x_{ij}\cdot y_{jg},$ linearized as $$z_{ijg} \le x_{ij}\quad \forall i,j,g. $$ $$z_{ijg} \le y_{jg} \quad \forall i,j,g.$$ $$z_{ijg} \ge x_{ij} + y_{jg} - 1 \quad \forall i,j,g.$$

Every individual must be in the same group as an anchor: $$\sum_{j,g} z_{ijg} = 1 \quad \forall i.$$



Let me see if I understood correctly: given that there is only one anchor per group, to enforce the division into m groups then I simply need to add the constraint Sum(anchors) = m?

That constraint would be correct but redundant. The first constraint (every group has exactly one anchor) is enforced for $g=1,\dots,m,$ so you get $m$ anchors and hence $m$ populated groups.

One last (?) note: this formulation introduces some symmetry into the model. If you take any optimal solution and permute the group numbers, you get another optimal solution. That can cause a solver to struggle a bit. If the symmetry does cause problems, you can get rid of it by adding the constraints $\sum_i i\cdot y_{i,g} + 1 \le \sum_i i \cdot y_{i, g+1}$ for $g=1,\dots,m-1.$ This forces the groups to be indexed in ascending order of the indices of their anchors.

Thanks @prubin!

I implemented the solution you proposed and it feels that it is missing one constraint. I have the matrix Y of all the anchors yig and all the three constraints you mentioned are fulfilled. However, the solver does not create m groups. The association between the variables and the anchors is missing. The example that made me notice this was when I wanted to divide 73 people into 10 groups but the solver made 11 groups.
I thought of multiplying the matrices X (variables) and Y (anchors) and then adding a constraint that the sum of each row of this resulting matrix should be equal to 1 (...)

However, multiplying variables would make the problem non linear. Do you have any suggestions? If I didn't explain myself properly, I can edit the question to explain this in greater detail.

Sorry, the solution I posted was missing the requirement that every individual be in a group with an anchor, which allowed it in your example to create a "rogue" group with no anchor. I've edited my answer to provide the fix. You have the right idea about multiplying $x$ and $y,$ and the product is easily linearized at the cost of adding a gaggle of new binary variables and constraints.

Thanks again prubin! Just to be sure, in order to add the last restriction (sum(z_ijg) =  1 for every i) I would need to store all the z_ijg variables in a n x n x m tensor. Then, for every i in [0, n-1], get z_i which is an n x m matrix and make the sum of all the elements of said matrix equal to 1. If this is correct, is there a way to optimize it? Given that x_ij = x_ji perhaps there is a way to make this more efficient.

Assuming that you specify $x_{ij}=x_{ji}$ as a constraint, a good quality solver will eliminate one variable and substitute the other during presolve, as well as replacing $x_{ii}$ with 1 wherever it occurs.
